# How do I use my Lunge Attack?

Tags: arcania

In ArcaniA, one of the first skills you unlock is the Lunge Attack in the Mettle skill tree. Its tooltip is

> *A Lunge Attack automatically bridges the distances to enemies that are
>   too far away for a normal strike.*

I don't seem to be "lunging" at enemies that are far away when I confront them with a melee weapon normally? How do I perform this special attack? Is there anything I need to do specifically or is it supposed to automatically happen?

[image: The skill in the Skill Tree]

Comment: It was a long time I played gothic 4, but it was easy to discover how it works. It's automatic, try to not smash button too fast, try to release movement. [Here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/207350/discussions/0/540741858800999830/) looks like a helpful post, try it and post answer if it works for you.

Comment: That post you linked to seems to be for a completely different game...? Ys Origin.

Comment: My bad, ignore the link =D I indeed hit a wrong game with my google-fu.